# Troubleshooting "algorithm" to investigate memory bloat with ramping memory usage on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks

I have a Ruby on Rails application with the following:

- Heroku Hobby Dyno
- Puma server
- Rails 4.2.10
- Ruby 2.4.7
- Using Jemalloc
- 6.000 unique visitors a day
- Applying puma rolling restarts (but it seems like it is not working)
- The website is heavily dependent on one controller with two views in it. This is important as Scout etc is difficult to be of use as knowing that the main controller has the problem is virtually useless.

I am having memory bloats according to the screen dump from Heroku below. As you can see the memory usage is pretty ok and then it suddenly ramps up until Heroku force restarts the app.

[image: Screen dump of memory usage on Heroku]

The interesting part here is that this started in January without no code updates or anything. I have had this exact issue on other apps before but unfortfunately, I can't recall exactly what made it better (I believe it was Jemalloc though).

I have spent quite some time with Scout and NewRelic but can't pinpoint anything. My theory has been that the error handling could be an issue as if the error handling is causing a memory problem it would become a positive feedback loop ever increasing the memory, but I have removed the error handling part competely and the problem persisted.

My main question here is: How should I go by to troubleshoot this, as in a mental algorithm to troubleshoot the issue? I would imagine the timestamps where the memory ramping starts is of great interest but what should I look for?

Is Garbage Collection tuning something of **great** interest here? Is the old Ruby version a very likely reason for memory issues?

Comment: Not that this is a solution but it turned out to be a middleware issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Ruby Memory Use](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use) from Heroku - Troubleshooting & Support.

> This article is intended to help you understand your application’s memory use and give you the tools to run your application without memory errors.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned, I have read that several times, but none of those examples helped really.